# Drag Direction wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

When using drag drop in wpf, is there a way to determine if the user is dragging left or dragging right?
I am using the standard drag events in wpf like, OnDragStarted, OnPreviewDragEnter etc...

Comment: Can you show your code?  I can't find OnDragStarted for wpf.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.labs.draggablelistboxitem.ondragstarted(v=vs.110).aspx

Probably more, but this is the first thing that came up.

Comment: I didn't find an OnDragStarted for the Window class.  If this is indeed the one the OP wants, then the Point properties will tell the start and end points.  The direction can be figured out from those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily calculate this yourself by calculating the difference of `DragEventArgs.GetPosition()`, say, each half second.

Returns a drop point that is relative to a specified

It returns a `Point` object, which has X and Y coordinates which you can use to determine the direction.